# combining for loops in Matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop

I am trying to make a program in matlab to get this numbers:

0 1 0

0 0.8 0.2

0 0.6 0.4

0 0.4 0.6

0 0.2 0.8

0 0 1

0.1 0.9 0

0.1 0.7 0.2

0.1 0.5 0.4

0.1 0.3 0.6

0.1 0.1 0.8

0.1 0 0.9

and so on but I cant make the program to reduce the values of the second and third column when the first column increases. This is my code. Thanks

```
lai=0:0.1:1;
laj=1:-0.2:0;
lat=0:0.2:1; 
for i=1,length(lai)
   for j=1,i
      for t=1,j
    j
    lam1(1,:)=lai;
   lam2(1,:)=laj;
   lam3(1,:)=lat;
        end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and do some thinking for what you require.

```
for i=0:0.1:0.1
    for j=0:0.2:1
        disp([i,j,1-j])
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks I solve that problem but now how do I save those results in a variable??

Comment: Are you trying to save it as a vector or matrix? I mean save all the values together or save them in 3 different variables.

Comment: You can create an empty matrix and update as the loop goes on. Like this mat= [mat; i,j,1-j];